# Write Delete statement on Select in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how to prepare a Delete statement based on the below select query.

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(OGUPMJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') jdedate from testdta.F5847036 WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(OGUPMJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') < (sysdate-30);
```

I am not able use

```
DELETE from TESTDTA.F5847036 where jdedate in (select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(OGUPMJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') jdedate from testdta.F5847036 WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(OGUPMJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') < (sysdate-30));
```

or

```
DELETE from TESTDTA.F5847036 where TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(OGUPMJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') jdedate in (select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(OGUPMJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') jdedate from testdta.F5847036 WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(OGUPMJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') < (sysdate-30));
```

Comment: Please give us more background on what "not able to use" means: to you get a parser error, or a runtime error? Is it a matter of syntax or a matter of query plan choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identifier `jdedate` is used as an alias in the SELECT query. It defines the column name in the result set. Column name aliases are not useful with delete (because there are no columns to return) and therefore not permitted by the syntax of the delete statement.

Remove the two occurences of the `jdedate` alias in the delete statement.